# Virtualbox switches workspace automatically after suspend on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, suspend, workspaces

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 14, reinstalled my Virtualbox (running version 5.1.22) for my Windows 7 VM. Everytime I launch my win 7 VM, I have a little script that switches to the 2nd viewport (or workspace) and launches the VM there. However, I don't understand why everytime my computer wakes back up from suspend, it does so in my Virtualbox Guest OS which has moved on its own from the 2nd to the 1st workspace. So I have to manually do a Super-S, and drag the VM back to the 2nd workspace...

I can't find any thread about this problem, does anyone know why this would be and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using your own script to move the VB window to another workspace, try using `CompizConfig Settings Manager` "Place Windows" panel, and set the "Windows with fixed viewport" as you can see in my example.

[image]

Comment: Spoke too fast! It does work when the screen shuts off  but not when the computer actually suspends. When the computer wakes back up, the Virtualbox VM is back on the 1st workspace... bummer. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Phybot I think it's a VB bug. I run my VB in WS1, and I see some weirdness with window placement myself. At least CCSM helped a bit. Worth at least a a vote...