# How to open a file from bash in another workspace

Tags: command-line, bash, screen, workspace-switcher

I am working on a project where a text file and tif file should be opened to full window to compare with each other.  So easiest way to do this is to open either one in another workspace. That means I want text file opened in active workspace and tif file opened in inactive workspace. Since there are many files I like to invocate them through bash script. Is this achievable from bash.

Comment: "So easiest way to do this is to open either one in another workspace. " are you sure? Side by side in 2 panes in gedit is not easier?

Comment: You might look at my answer for CCSM at https://askubuntu.com/questions/911812/virtualbox-switches-workspace-automatically-after-suspend-on-ubuntu-16-04/911883#911883 and see if it's usable in your situation. If so, let me know, and I can write up an answer.

Comment: @Rinzwind line width of text is demanding full screen. @ heynnemma It is a good solution. I would use it now. But a bash solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I launch all my applications and files simultaneously from bash in the current workspace and three other workspaces using this one line command. You can modify this command to make it more concise

```
wmctrl -o 1920,0  && sh "/home/user1/Desktop/one2.sh" & sleep 0.5 && wmctrl -o 3840,0  &&  sh "/home/user1/Desktop/one3.sh" & sleep 1.5 && wmctrl -o 5760,0  && sh "/home/user1/Desktop/one4.sh" &
```